# How do I delete my Google+ account while keeping Gmail?

Tags: google-plus, account-management

How do you completely get rid of Google Plus and still use Gmail and not have it pester you about registering for Google+?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the prevention of pestering part (that's internal marketing, after all), but you *can* delete your Google+ profile.

At the bottom of your [Google+ settings](https://www.google.com/settings/plus) is a link:

> **Disable Google+**
>
> You can disable Google+ (or delete your entire Google profile) [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/downgrade/).

On the subsequent page, you can either

- Delete Google+ content, or
- Delete your entire Google profile

I expect the first is what you want. The page also notes:

> If you delete Google+, Google attempts to restore your experience of other Google products to the way it was before you joined Google+ and to permanently delete your Google+ circles, posts, and comments. If you delete your Google profile, you delete Google+ as well as other services and their data that depend on a Google profile. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1044503?p=downgrade&rd=1)

Which further links to [this Google support page about "Downgrade from Google+"](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1044503?p=downgrade&rd=1), which also happens to give a step-by-step on how to delete your Google+ account.

(I didn't follow the steps all the way through, because I want to keep my G+ account.)